# Making a toy language interpreter, AST variables and scopes

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

as in the title, i recently started working on a parser/interpreter in c++ with a friend, that will later be integrated in a bigger project (if it works); we decided to start making the classes we will use for the abstract syntax tree, and we will work later on the proper parser side.
We started with the concepts of scope and variable. Doing some search we found an example in which every scope has a symbol table and a link to previous scope's one, so if a variable isn't found in current scope, it will look in the upper one and so on.
The first thing i had to point out from this example, is that trying to access a variable which is many scopes up in the stack or even non existent, would have an high cost (worst case scenario as high as stack depth). I was like… nah we can do better.

The result of our thinking was the following:
a single symbol table at the root of the program, consisting in a map of strings to a stack of variables

```
map<string, stack<variable>> table;
```

then each scope would hold a set of strings, which would be the ones allocated in that scope

```
set<string> allocated;
```

When a variable "a" is allocated, the string of its name gets added into that scope local set, then a new variable is pushed into e table (table["a"].push()). 
Accessing that variable for editing or reading would be done reading the top of that same position (table["a"].top())
And finally the scope destructor would loop through all elements in allocated and pop from the stacks in the map.

```
for(variable_name in allocated)
    {
    table[variable_name].pop();
    }
```

This way would make allocation, read and write O(1) in any case. 
Here come my 2 questions:

1) Is having to save strings for every variable both in the table and in the scope, together with having to loop through all of them at the end of a scope, inefficient, compared to the many-tables-system which would just have to delete an array?

2) The example i found was being not-so-efficient on purpose being a very beginner tutorial thing, or there's something i'm missing that makes it more worth than the idea me and my friend came out with?

Comment: I would suggest that whether you are fretting over a stacked based, linked table based or other aspect at this stage is probably overkill. Make it work, make it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no absolute answer here; it depends on the precise nature of scopes in your language and also on your programming style. My advice is to first get it working, and then see if it needs to be improved. Whatever you choose to go with as a symbol table implementation, make sure to hide the implementation details behind an ADT prototype, which will define the behaviour of the symbol table. Then you can easily swap in a different implementation if you need to.

Anyway, here are a few datapoints:

1. Scope nesting is not usually very deep. Indeed, for most languages, deeply-nested scopes are considered poor style.
2. Your proposal involves creating a hash table for every scope anyway. That's not really necessary; you can do the whole thing with a single hash table for all lookups and a stack to mark the scope boundaries. The symbol table is a `unordered_map<name, definition>` and the scope stack is `stack<pair<name, definition>>`.  (I'm assuming C++. Here, `name` might just be an alias for `std::string` but see below. `definition` contains the metadata you need to store for each symbol. It's not necessary to keep them separate like that; you could use a single type and then use a `set` instead of a `map`.) The `definition` in the scope stack is the definition from some outer scope or an indication that in the outer scope the variable is undefined. There also needs to be a sentinel value (either for the name or the definition) which indicates the beginning of a scope.

   When you enter a scope, you push the sentinel onto the scope stack. Then each time a variable is defined, it's previous definition is pushed onto the scope stack and the new definition is stored into the symbol table. When you leave the scope, you pop the scope stack back to the last sentinel, replacing each variable with its previous definition as you go.
3. There are lots of different kinds of scopes in a typical language. Here's a few examples:

   - Closure scopes. If you allow functions to be defined inside functions, then some outer scopes are actually closures. These require different handling than scopes in an outer block in the same function, although the symbol table handling isn't really different other than tracking the metadata correctly.
   - Global scope and/or module scopes.
   - Compound object ("class") member name scopes. These don't nest the same way block scopes do, but depending on your language's name lookup algorithm, they might still be part of a chained name search.
4. It's obviously simpler to make names `std::string` objects, but you'll end up creating an awful lot of duplicate strings, which need to be string compared to other strings. Modern computers are fast enough that none of that matters, but you might want to think about optimising it anyway. I prefer to "intern" strings by putting them into a `std::set<std::string>` (or equivalent) and then using element  pointers instead of the string itself. This has two benefits:

   - Each string is only stored and allocated once, which saves allocation overhead. Modern allocation libraries are pretty fast, but it still makes little sense keeping a zillion copies of the same string, one for each use of the name in a program. Keeping the names in an intern table might make increase their lifetimes, but in practice it's not much of an issue, particularly since many programmers recycle names in different scopes.
   - Comparing names can be done with pointer comparison rather than character-by-character comparison. That's a bit faster, since it doesn't require a loop. Again, modern hardware makes this unnecessary, but it's still something of a plus. If you then use the pointer instead of the string as the symbol table key,  you save the overhead of computing the hash of the key on every lookup. That's another measurable though not revolutionary improvement.